# Where to store images obtained from the server

Tags: android, bitmap, drawable

I am downloading a number of small images from the server. My question is: where do I store them? The images are icon size and I am expecting at the very most 100 of them. I want to use a HashMap to store them. But I am wondering if I should be storing them on the SD card. And if I decide to store them on the SD card: Do I have to "inflate" the bitmap each time a user calls the image (which is used  on multiple activities) or would I be storing them in a data structure anyway at that point? To me the obvious answer is HashMap. But just in case I overlook something, does anyone know reasons for which way I should go?

Answer (score 0):

Why not cache them on external storage or internal storage? This is actually how Android Gallery has done. You can find cache file at /sdcard/Android/data/gallery_package/cache/cache_file. In Gallery, you can access Picasa data which will be downloaded by gallery and cached to local disk. when drawing these data on screen, you can load them from cache directly.